# Обновление информации в виджете из другого потока

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt5, pyqt

Как сделать постоянный вызов accept, чтобы обновлять виджет QTextEdit?

Просто Thread не работает:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import requests
from threading import Thread

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.lay)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.id = 'default'
        self.idl = QLineEdit()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.idl)

        self.log = QPushButton()
        self.log.setText('Connect')
        self.log.clicked.connect(self.setId)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.log)

        self.board = QTextEdit()
        self.board.textChanged.connect(self.send)
        self.board.setMinimumSize(1200, 700,)
        self.board.setStyleSheet('font-size:20px;')
        self.lay.addWidget(self.board)
        thread = Thread(target=self.accept)
        thread.start()
    def setId(self):
        self.id = self.idl.text()

    def send(self):
        requests.get(f'http://localhost:8080/set/{self.id}/{self.board.toPlainText()}/...')

    def accept(self):
        self.board.setText(requests.get(f'http://localhost:8080/get/{self.id}/...').text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Если делать так как описано выше, то возникает ошибка:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x104051140), parent's thread is QThread(0x100403ac0), current thread is QThread(0x10409a0a0)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно и через поток решить данную задачку, только лучше воспользоваться каким-нибудь механизмом передачи данных из одного потока в другой - в Qt таким механизмом являются сигналы и слоты.

```py
# other imports
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
import time

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # Сигнал о пришедших/полученных данных
    signal_incomingText = pyqtSignal(str)

    #...
    def initUI(self):
       #...
       # args=(self) добавил в качестве демонстрации передачи ссылки
       # на главное окно приложения на тот случай, если бы метод accept
       # был отдельной функцией (чтобы было бы правильнее)
       thread = Thread(target=self.accept, args=(self,))

       # Соединяем сигнал со слотом (обновляем текст)
       # Вторым параметром можно указать Qt.DirectConnection,  Qt.QueueConnection
       self.signal_incomingText.connect(lambda text: self.board.setText(text))
      
       # старт потока
       thread.start()

    # Лучше бы такие функции объявлять отдельно, чтобы не путать
    # методы одного класса с другим, а частности методом отдельного потока.
    def accept(self, windowRef):
       while(True):
           # запрос
           txt = requests.get(f'http://localhost:8080/get/{self.id}/...').text

           # отправляем полученный результат в слот (у нас это ламбда)
           self.signal_incomingText.emit(txt)

           # Ждем какое-то время (1 сек)
           time.sleep(1)
```

Параметры соединения в connect можно посмотреть [здесь](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/core/Qt.ConnectionType.html)

Comment: а нормально что переменная потока локально создается? Что там у нее с временем жизни? Я бы сделал мебмером класса или даже создать отдельнный класс контроллера, который нужно соеденить через сигнал/слот с MainWindow и в нем гонять тред(как член класса)

Comment: @JK_Action в данном примере (примере!) - нормально. Поток будет жить пока дело его живет, то есть метод accept! А вот если его надо будет грохнуть в процессе, то есть получить доступ к нему по имени и терминировать, то тогда вы конечно правы (и это хорошее замечание, но так у автора), но вопрос был не об этом :)

Comment: Теперь текст дергается, и ничего нельзя ввести (

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica вы хотите чтобы была возможность вводить  текст вручную в поле, в котором раз в секунду текст обновляется программно? То есть, фактически,  изменять одно и тоже поле одновременно с разных сторон? )

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica немного ввел вас в заблуждение - надо импортировать pyqtSignal (для PyQt5), а не Signal (это для PySide2). Исправил в ответе. Попробуйте поиграть с параметром подключения в коннекте поставьте `Qt.DirrectConnection`, а потом `Qt.QueueConnection`  https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-signals-using-keyword-arguments

Comment: На первый вопрос да, на второй — спасибо, я уже нагуглил.

Comment: Ломаю голову, ну как это сделать (

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica если вам надо менять одно и тоже поле с разных "концов", то можно попробовать либо изменить программный интервал внесения изменений (скажем раз в 20 секунд, причем во время внесения изменений блокировать поле для ручного ввода), либо ... А вы ничего не мудрите? ))

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica вообще задача интересная, но надо больше информации. Может быть в тексте выставлять якоря к которым привязывать другой виджет, поверх поля для текста и вот в него уже и вносить программные изменения?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica вот пример вставки в документ svg-файла https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-richtext-textobject-example.html, в принципе так можно вставить любой виджет в документ, а уже этот виджет наполнять программными данными