# PyQT. Почему не работает show() в потоке?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Если `showLabel()` используется вне потока, то всё работает.
Если я пытаюсь поместить `showLabel()` в поток, то программа зависает и вылетает именно на строке `self.label.show()`.

В чём может быть проблема и как это можно решить?

Код (очень сокращён):

```
import sys
from threading import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)

    def showLabel(self):
        self.label = QLabel('Label', self)
        self.label.move(100, 100)
        self.label.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    showLabel()  # Без потока 
    Thread(target=window.showLabel).start()  # С потоком
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135341/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: вызывайте нужные сигналы или слоты для виджета в основном потоке с помощью `invokeMethod` с аргументом QueuedConnection или BlockingQueuedConnection, чтобы не плодить слишком много коннектов

Answer (score 2):

Элементы графического интерфейса (**все**, что унаследовано или связано с подклассом `QWidget`) **должны быть созданы и доступны только из основного потока Qt**.

```
import sys
#from threading import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Thread(QThread):
    dataThread = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.number = 1

    def run(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.dataThread.emit(f"Label {self.number}")
            self.number += 1
            self.msleep(1000)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(100, 100)
        self.showLabel('Label   ')
        
        self.worker = Thread()
        self.worker.dataThread.connect(self.showLabel)
        self.worker.start() 

    def showLabel(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)  
        self.label.adjustSize() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(500, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у меня ответ тоже правильный, а то я засомневался чуть-чуть ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ответ у вас может быть и правильный (я не проверял), но вы не ответили на вопрос: "Почему не работает show() в потоке?"

Comment: @zEvilCube я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from threading import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


class Window(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.signal.connect(self.showLabel)  
 
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)

    def showLabel(self):
        self.label = QLabel('Label', self)
        self.label.move(100, 100)
        self.label.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.showLabel()  # Без потока 
    Thread(target=window.signal.emit).start()  # С потоком
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```